# Not receiving push notification using AWS SNS android

Tags: amazon-sns

I am developing android app that receives push notification using AWS SNS. The basic flow is i receive subscribe id,subscribe secret key and topic to subscribe from api.I create the endpoint by using provided platform application ARN and subscribe to that topic.

My code is:

```
AmazonSNSClient client;
SharedPreferences userPreferences;
ProfileData profileData;
String token;

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(ARScreen.Container... containers) {
    ARScreen.Container container = containers[0];
    profileData = container.profileData;
    userPreferences = container.userPreferences;
    token = container.token;
    BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(profileData.getSubscribeId(), profileData.getSubscribeSecret());
    client = new AmazonSNSClient(credentials);
    client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1));
    registerWithSNS(token);
    return null;
}

@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
@SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "unchecked"})
public void registerWithSNS(String regId) {

    String endpointArn = retrieveEndpointArn();

    boolean updateNeeded = false;
    boolean createNeeded = (null == endpointArn);

    if (createNeeded) {
        // No platform endpoint ARN is stored; need to call createEndpoint.
        endpointArn = createEndpoint(regId);
        createNeeded = false;
    }

    System.out.println("Retrieving platform endpoint data...");
    // Look up the platform endpoint and make sure the data in it is current, even if
    // it was just created.
    try {
        GetEndpointAttributesRequest geaReq =
                new GetEndpointAttributesRequest()
                        .withEndpointArn(endpointArn);
        GetEndpointAttributesResult geaRes =
                client.getEndpointAttributes(geaReq);

        updateNeeded = !geaRes.getAttributes().get("Token").equals(regId)
                || !geaRes.getAttributes().get("Enabled").equalsIgnoreCase("true");

    } catch (NotFoundException nfe) {
        // We had a stored ARN, but the platform endpoint associated with it
        // disappeared. Recreate it.
        createNeeded = true;
    }

    if (createNeeded) {
        createEndpoint(regId);
    }

    System.out.println("updateNeeded = " + updateNeeded);

    if (updateNeeded) {
        // The platform endpoint is out of sync with the current data;
        // update the token and enable it.
        System.out.println("Updating platform endpoint " + endpointArn);
        Map attribs = new HashMap();
        attribs.put("Token", regId);
        attribs.put("Enabled", "true");
        SetEndpointAttributesRequest saeReq =
                new SetEndpointAttributesRequest()
                        .withEndpointArn(endpointArn)
                        .withAttributes(attribs);
        client.setEndpointAttributes(saeReq);

    }

    String subscriptionId = client.subscribe(new SubscribeRequest()
            .withEndpoint(endpointArn)
            .withProtocol("application")
            .withTopicArn(profileData.getSnstopic())
    ).getSubscriptionArn();

    System.out.println("Id" + subscriptionId);
    SubscribeRequest subscribeRequest = new SubscribeRequest(profileData.getSnstopic(), "application", endpointArn);
    SubscribeResult result = client.subscribe(subscribeRequest);

    if (result != null) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isSubscribed", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
}

/**
 * @return never null
 */
private String createEndpoint(String token) {

    String endpointArn;
    try {
        System.out.println("Creating platform endpoint with token " + token);
        CreatePlatformEndpointRequest cpeReq =
                new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest()
                        .withPlatformApplicationArn("My Platform Application ARN")
                        .withToken(token);
        CreatePlatformEndpointResult cpeRes = client
                .createPlatformEndpoint(cpeReq);
        endpointArn = cpeRes.getEndpointArn();
    } catch (InvalidParameterException ipe) {
        String message = ipe.getErrorMessage();
        System.out.println("Exception message: " + message);
        Pattern p = Pattern
                .compile(".*Endpoint (arn:aws:sns[^ ]+) already exists " +
                        "with the same token.*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(message);
        if (m.matches()) {
            // The platform endpoint already exists for this token, but with
            // additional custom data that
            // createEndpoint doesn't want to overwrite. Just use the
            // existing platform endpoint.
            endpointArn = m.group(1);
        } else {
            // Rethrow the exception, the input is actually bad.
            throw ipe;
        }
    }
    storeEndpointArn(endpointArn);
    return endpointArn;
}

/**
 * @return the ARN the app was registered under previously, or null if no
 * platform endpoint ARN is stored.
 */
private String retrieveEndpointArn() {
    // Retrieve the platform endpoint ARN from permanent storage,
    // or return null if null is stored.
    return userPreferences.getString("endPointArn", null);
}


/**
 * Stores the platform endpoint ARN in permanent storage for lookup next time.
 */
@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
private void storeEndpointArn(String endpointArn) {
    // Write the platform endpoint ARN to permanent storage.
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("endPointArn", endpointArn);
    editor.commit();
}
```

I can see my subscription id in the log console.The problem is I am not receiving any push notification related with that topic.
Did I miss something in the code?? Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: did you add the api key as credential while creating platform application ARN ???

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the configuration properly set ( I recommend to use MobileHub to link any service from AWS,e.g. SNS with Push and Cognito)
you only have to pay attention to your PushListenerService that you have implemented on your app.

Firstly, verify that you have added the next lines on your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<!-- BEGIN - PUSH NOTIFICATIONS WITH GOOGLE CLOUD MESSAGING (GCM) -->

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.yourpackagename" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".push.service.PushListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <!-- END - PUSH NOTIFICATIONS WITH GOOGLE CLOUD MESSAGING (GCM) -->
```

And also, in your PushListenerService, make sure you get messages sent from Firebase and Amazon MobileHub console:

```
/**
 * Helper method to extract SNS message from bundle.
 *
 * @param data bundle
 * @return message string from SNS push notification
 */
public static String getMessage(Bundle data) {
    // If a push notification is sent as plain text, then the message appears in "default".
    // Otherwise it's in the "message" for JSON format.
    String result = data.containsKey("default") ? data.getString("default") : data.getString(
            "message", "");
    if(result.isEmpty()){
        result = data.getBundle("notification").get("body").toString();
    }

    return result;
}
```